# Steganographic Maze of Ciphers, Riddles and Rhyme!

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme, steganography, reverse-puzzling

Go with the flow!!!

**INSTRUCTIONS**

> Done with my time on this planet, I left you with my creation.
>   I'm hidden in two ways below, one puzzled, while the other is a direct mention.
>   I know you will shortly reveal my identity, and rest all will be fine.
>   If you ask me for a hint, I say, unscramble the rhyme.

**The Rhyme** *(Rhyming Scheme - AABBCC... As Always :) )*

> There were not many ways;
>   I believed it was nothing but Gee!
>   I had colors to prove.
>   Not sure about others though;
>   Yes, I was quite better with numbers.
>   While the world was dealing with wars;
>   But I gave you three rules of a move.
>   They used to intrigue me.
>   I only knew universally related members.
>   Not aware about other humans;
>   Often I watched the waterfalls;
>   Every kid now fears one of mine;

**The Cipher**

> Xac pzirjxvd bs jseubho pvaxvjk hxgrnrhfvia

**The Rhyme**

> Two tails of the second; Fourth of the first.
>   Inverted couples from the second; Breaks my thirst!

**The Cipher** *(Last-First-Last-First)*

> Jon arp, auwhe bthbzkt avita wa qulqywi.
>   Cotzf eiet rtgab, ghexhr cefmqtel!
>   Zf eqktvbi, feakb yzcntv yofmanltbhce.
>   Lbhdr wigmf donvq nognhdigo etgab? Fz, hxzr ts tv ripeialtbwa -
>   Mebvt woomq qaearwy, B trqt Q-und ptzg gekg jteklyj!

**Formula -**

> (Answer of Rhyme 1 ➜ Key to Cipher 1 ➜ Answer of Cipher 1) ➜ Answer of Rhyme 2 ➜ Key to Cipher 2 ➜ Answer of Cipher 2 ➜ **Final Answer!**

**HINT**

> Try building a rhyme. May be post a partial solution. Soon you shall figure out your next move.

<sub><sup>(Note-There is a reverse puzzling tag for a reason!)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Rhyme** (#1) - goes together thus:

> Not aware about about humans; I only knew universally related members.
>  Every kid now fears one of mine; Yes, I was quite better with numbers.
>  While the world was dealing with wars; I had colors to prove.
>  There were not many ways; But I gave you three rules of a move.
>  Often I watched the waterfalls; They used to intrigue me.
>  Not sure about others though; I believed it was nothing but Gee!

@ChrisCudmore and I separately got (most of) this assembled.

Which Hints To:

> Sir Isaac Newton - 3 rules of motion, Optics, G, law of universal gravitation.
>  The hinting is both "direct" and "puzzled"—in the riddle, and in the first letters of each line.

**The Cipher** #1 -

> decodes to: ***Key inventor of noxious looking alternative***
>  Find this by using Vigenére to **encode** the cipher-text with the key "NEWTON", the solution of the first Rhyme—making use of the [reverse-puzzling](/questions/tagged/reverse-puzzling) tag.
>  **[credit @Chris Cudmore for noticing this!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47654/30633)**

Its answer:

> First letters of the plaintext are K I O N L A.
>  The "noxious looking alternative", and (KIONLA*) → NIKOLA, give us Nikola Tesla, pioneer of Alternating Current, the dangerous looking alternative (heh!) to DC.

**The Rhyme** (#2) -

> Tells us to take the two tails (last two letters) of NIKOLA,
>  then the fourth letter of "the first" (meaning NEWTON),
>  and then the "inverted couples" of NIKOLA again which will break our thirst.
>    for that last bit, we separate NIKOLA into a couple (NI) and what breaks our thirst (KOLA "cola")
>    and then invert our couple to give IN.
>  so put all that together, it gives
>  **LA** **T** **IN**

**The Cipher** (#2) -

> Use **LATIN** on the cipher text, get this:
>
>    You see, about bazooka sixth on fusilli.
>    Jggof lari raynq, gowkwr jwsbqawy!
>    Of lixivia, start loculi nomenclature.
>    Stusr datbf kgakq ugtchkatd eaynq? Fg, zkor ak gk rphrxaslola -
>    Twokt dgbbq xsrprdq, O irxl D-jnk hgog nwxv jawxayq!
>
>  But if you "go with the flow" - which apparently means, do one line at a time in TechIdiot speak :) - it decrypts to this:
>
>    **You see, about bazooka sixth on fusilli.
>
>    Roars till eight, tweeze remedies!
>
>    Of lixivia, start loculi nomenclature.
>
>    Above lines sound confusing right? So, here is an explanation -
>
>    Being loved falsely, I left X-mas part very wierdly!**

**The Home Stretch**
We've deciphered the last cipher.  Now to solve it.

> With a late edit, we're now told to look at "last-first".  So let's take the last and first letters of each word (thus skipping the first letter of the first word, then taking the first and last of the remaining words) in the plaintext.  Doing that through the first three lines, you get:
>
>  **Use atbash on first letters of last line**
>
>  Taking its advice, we finally arrive at the last of the puzzle:
>  **YouRoCked**

Thanks, I think?! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Solution**

We may need to work backwards on this puzzle. I was able to derive a key for at least part of the final cipher.

The key is

> inlat

There were three words that ended up giving it away:

> Q-und -> X-mas (key:tinl), B -> I (key:t), Fz -> So (key:nl)

And the decrypted plaintext is

> Bbc ayh, njwow oihirxi acagp wh ihaqfov. Roars till eight, tweeze remedies! Rs tqrliqi, mwnzb frpctc qbumhfyibour. Above lines sound confusing right? So, here is an explanation - Being loved falsely, I left X-mas part very wierdly!

The first and third lines are still encrypted. Not sure if they require another round of decryption from here, or if they need to be independently decrypted from their original text.

**EDIT: This is my first attempt at unscrambling the first poem:**

> Often I watched the waterfalls;
>  They used to intrigue me.
>  While the world was dealing with wars;
>  I believed it was nothing but Gee!
>  Not sure about others though;
>  Yes, I was quite better with numbers.
>  Not aware about other humans;
>  I only knew universally related members.
>  There were not many ways;
>  But I gave you three ways to move.
>  Every kid now fears one of mine;
>  I had colors to prove.

Am I in the ballpark?

Comment: There is a reason why it says **Go with the flow** you took a jump and hence it's messed. :D And I am not sure if the key is right ;) Again, start with the rhyme. :)

Comment: I was gonna hold off but since you invited a partial solution, I figured this was at least some added information to help others. :)

Comment: No worries. But I said _Try building a rhyme. May be post a partial solution._ ;) And, believe me, that will be an easier job that what you did up there :)

Comment: I edited my partial answer with an attempt at unscrambling the poem. Definitely not my strong point! Not sure if I'm in the ballpark...

Comment: Good try. You need to have the required rhyming scheme though. +1 for the attempt :)

Comment: The key is LATIN, and you have to do it line by line.  INLAT is a cycle, so it worked for some lines.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the first cipher is:

> Key inventor of noxious looking alternative

because

> Using the REVERSE PUZZLING hint, I ENCRYPTED the cipher text with NEWTON as the key using Vigeniere's cipher.